# When trying to install CrossOver deb I get "Error: Dependency is not satisfiable libpng12-0"

Tags: package-management, software-installation

I have tried to install `libpng12-0` but it still doesn't work.

Here:

[image: screenshot]

How do I fix this?

Comment: This seems like a bug in crossover's installer (requires an obsolete package), not a problem with Ubuntu.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Which version of CrossOver are you trying to install? Did you try to install the most recent version?

Comment: If you got the mosr recent .deb ( `wget http://crossover.codeweavers.com/redirect/crossover.deb` ) then just install it with apt i.e `sudo apt install /path/to/crossover.deb` It will install fine on 16.04 thru 18.04 as the dependency is " libpng12-0 | libpng16-16"

Comment: **Reviewers**: This question is **not about a bug** in CrossOver because there isn't a bug in CrossOver. The old version of CrossOver was looking for an older version of PNG library - runtime, but the package maintainer's version of PNG library - runtime also works for this version of CrossOver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PNG library - runtime has been upgraded from libpng12-0 to libpng16-16 in Ubuntu 18.04 and later (at least up to 19.10). To install it open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install libpng16-16
```

Create a symbolic link at `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0` which references to file `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16`

```
sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0
```

Comment: The last part of this instruction seems a bit confusing to me. It would be sufficient to run `sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0` I think - no need for any copying and renaming.

Comment: @karel Thank You https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrDzv.gif

Answer (score 1):

The proposed solution described above didn't work for me on Ubuntu 19.04 with Cisco PacketTracer 7.2.2:

```
./PacketTracer7: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0: version `PNG12_0' not found (required by ./libQt5WebKit.so.5)
./PacketTracer7: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0: version `PNG12_0' not found (required by ./libQt5Gui.so.5)
```

What did work for me was:

- download the `libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb` package
- manually extract it: `dpkg -x libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb libpng`
- copy the library to the PacketTracer `bin` directory like so: `cp libpng12/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0.54.0 /opt/pt/bin`
- create a symlink: `ln -s /opt/pt/bin/libpng12.so.0.54.0 /opt/pt/bin/libpng12.so.0`
- PROFIT

Not sure why Cisco provides all the required libs in the /opt/pt/bin like Qt and such, but somehow 'forgot' to include the older libpng12 lib...